# MySql WorkBench "Execute Query into Text Output" option not showing full result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have executed a following in **Execute Query into Text Output** from mysql workbench 5.2.4 version.

**it is not showing full output., answer set is trimmed.**

> show create table the_re.user_list;

```
+ ---------- + ----------------- +
| Table      | Create Table      |
+ ---------- + ----------------- +
| user_list | CREATE TABLE `user_list` (
  `unique_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_` date  NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_` date NOT NULL,
  `t_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `d_date` date NOT NULL,
  `d_tim... |
+ ---------- + ----------------- +
```

the above result is ends with following statement. There are few more texts missing after this.

> **`d_tim... |**

Could you please tell me how to display full result text as i need to execute 'N' query result in single text output?

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version (6.0.7 atm).

For getting create statements you can simply right click on the table in the schema tree and choose "Send to SQL Editor.." -> "Create Statement".

Comment: I need to get all ddls in one out put window. so, wanted to execute show create table command in one shot for all tables. but the text output is trimming output